# Can't change HTTP Vary header from PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have a test server running CentOS, and changing the `Vary` header there through PHP via:

```
header('Vary: Accept');
```

works as expected (it's added to the `Accept-Encoding` value that Apache already adds by itself). On the Ubuntu 10 LTS production server it does not. I tried to search the web for answers, but couldn't find any. Even setting:

```
header('Vary: Accept',true); // forces the header to be replaced
```

won't change the `Vary` header. Any help would be appreciated.

The server is running Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) and PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26.

Comment: You state `Vary: Accept`, but mention `Accept-Encoding` - shouldn't you be sending `Vary: Accept-Encoding` in this case? "it's added to the Accept-Encoding value that's being set by Apache" - what do you mean by this? The `Vary: Accept` header tells the local cache to take the `Accept` header into account when caching a response.

Comment: @w3d: I didn't explicitly set the `Accept-Encoding` part, so it must have been Apache itself, because I've set up mod_deflate.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for clarifying (I think I must have read it wrong earlier!)

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have the environment `force-no-vary` set to TRUE in your configuration, or simply try to set it to FALSE in your virtual host configuration. More details about this and how you should proceed, you can fine here: [Environment Variables in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html).

Also, there are modules that may override this header when the response is served to the client - for example, [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#proxies), but as you mentioned, you don't get this header back at all so my best guess remains the `force-no-vary` environment setting.

Comment: I do have mod_deflate activated on both servers. But only on the CentOS one I can add more values to it, not on the Ubuntu one. I'll try the env-var.